# CSS Grid. Centrar items

Tags: css, grid

Pienso que debe ser algo básico, pero no encuentro la forma de centrar mis items dentro de un contenedor display:grid. En este link pueden encontrar el ejemplo corriendo: https://lab.ruzestudio.com/grid/

Aclaraciones importantes:

1- No quiero centrar el texto, sino que las cajas naranjas se vayan cargando alineadas al centro y no a la izquierda.

2- La idea es usar la estructura en contenidos dinámicos, no se cuantas cajas naranjas puede haber, por ende una solución basada en alinear un item puntal no me serviría.

3- ACTUALIZACIÓN: agregué al contenedor las propiedades justify-items:center; y align-items:center; pero no funciono. Se puede ver en el link

[image: asi queda mi contenido]

y acá esta el codigo:

```
<style>
        *{
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        .grid{
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: auto;
            grid-gap: 30px;
            padding: 30px;
            justify-content: center;
            align-content: center;

            
        }
        .grid > div{
            background: orange;                                             
            display: inline-block;
        }
    </style>        
    
    <div class="grid" d="5" t="3" m="2">
        <div>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
        </div>
        <div>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
        </div>
        <div>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
        </div>
        <div>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
        </div>
        <div>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
        </div>
        <div>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
        </div>
        <div>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
        </div>
        <div>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        // tomo atributo d y lo establesco como cantidad e columnas.
        var grid = document.querySelectorAll('.grid');
        
        grid.forEach( (g)=>{                
            let cantidad = g.getAttribute('d');             
            g.style.gridTemplateColumns = "repeat("+cantidad+",1fr)";   
        })          
    </script>
```

Muchas gracias!

Comment: es decir que la caja 6 esté abajo de la caja 2 y asi sucesivamente?

Comment: Claro, en este caso si.

Comment: El problema es que justify-content: center; te centra el contenido completo en base al contenedor padré, es como si te pintase un contenedor que envuelve los divs y en base a eso centra todo el contenido, no los centra de forma independiente, es mas facil hacer eso con flexbox.

Comment: Claro si mi contenedor fuera mas grande o el total de mi template de items seria mas chico podria ver el justify-content en accion por lo que entiendo. Pero por lo que veo el grid en su funcionamiento es mas como una tabla, no? O sea lo que estoy queriendo hacer con CSS Grid no se pude?

Answer (score 1):

```html
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="pyramid"></div>
    </div>

    <script>
        let j, i, row, itemCount, ulChildren;
        let uniqueID = 0;

        function liElements() {
            let pyramid = document.getElementById("pyramid");
            /* i --> elementID, j --> nr of rows / rowID */

            for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                row = document.createElement("ul");
                pyramid.appendChild(row);
                row.setAttribute("id", "ul-" + j);
                itemCount = 2 * (j + 1) - 1; //put 1,3,5... elements into ul-s

                let ulChildren = "";

                for (i = 0; i < itemCount; i++) {
                    uniqueID++;
                    ulChildren += "<li>ITEM" + " " + (i + 1) + "-" + uniqueID + "</li>";
                    row.innerHTML = ulChildren;
                }
            }
        }

        liElements();
    </script>

    <style>
        body {
            font-size: 10px;
            font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
        }
        
        #container {
            margin: auto;
            background: #dedede;
            overflow: hidden;
            padding: 1rem 0;
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            justify-content: center;
        }
        
        #intro {
            margin: 0 1rem 2rem 1rem;
            text-align: center;
        }
        
        ul {
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            justify-content: center;
            margin: 0 auto;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        
        li {
            list-style-type: none;
            color: #dec1ff;
            background: #7d70ba;
            padding: 0.3rem 0.5rem;
            margin: 0 0.3rem 0.5rem 0;
            border-radius: 5px;
            display: inline-block;
        }
    </style>
</body>
```

espero te sirva

Comment: Gracias! me gusta la solución que propones con JS y Flexbox. Me quedo igual con la duda si Css Grid permite hacer algo como esto?